# Telegram download media from chat bot in python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

A bot forward to me some media file but I can't download media from bot chat. No errors and no log warning/message.It crash only. I usually use download_media() with no difficulty, but this is the first time I try to download from bot chat please any advice ,

There are no errors

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import errors
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('telethon').setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def login(client, phone):
print("Start...")
await client.connect()
if not await client.is_user_authorized():
    print("Requesting auth..")
    await client.send_code_request(phone)
    await client.sign_in(phone, int(input('Enter code: ')))
try:
    async with client.takeout(finalize=False) as takeout:
        print("Connected...")
        return takeout
except errors.TakeoutInitDelayError:
    print("Please confirm and restart (+42777)")
    return False
```

async def start():

```
api_id = 
api_hash = 
tel = 
client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)

takeout = await login(client, tel)
if not takeout:
    loop.stop()
channel = await takeout.get_input_entity('https://t.me/xxxxx_Bot')
msgs = await takeout.get_messages(channel) # get message object
print(msgs) # print message OK
await client.download_media(msgs)  # has no effect , no error or log strings
loop.stop()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
   task_start = loop.create_task(start())
   loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass
finally:
   pass
```

How to download media from bot chat ?
thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has no fault.

```
msgs = await takeout.get_messages(channel)
```

get_messages() only gets read messages....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).